# Why does Dr. Jenner seem to behave like he has more than a day left to survive?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Jenner's behaviour (towards the end of series 1) consistently seems a bit odd given the situation with the lack of fuel and imminent explosion, which he fully knows about.

For instance, when Jenner spills some kind of harmful liquid in the lab where the TS-19 samples are stored, he seems absolutely distraught that these precious samples have been destroyed. This would seem to make perfect sense, but Jenner knew full well at the time that Vi was going to blow up the entire building in a day or so anyway, and he was nowhere close to finding a cure - certainly not something he could create and distribute in a day.

On a related note, given the relatively imminent explosion, why did he seem so intent to command Rick and his group to not plug anything electric in, go easy on the hot water, etc.? Again, surely with the time they had left, a games console wouldn't have made much difference?

The only thing I could think of was that he was hoping out for some form of "miracle" for extra time / fuel - but then if that was the case, why not make use of Rick and his team, and send them out the following day to scrounge as much diesel as they could for the generators? They were in the middle of a city - surely they could have taken some of the empty oil drums and filled them up with fuel from the many cars around?

Perhaps I'm just being over-analytical, but something just doesn't seem to add up about that whole scene.

Comment: Dr. Jenner comes about as a man of structure and discipline. Therefore, even though he knows the inevitable future of his lab, his principles and way of living have supremacy over the situation. Also, keep in mind that hope is always there, even when everything else is lost.

Answer (score 12):

When we first see Jenner, solving the riddle of the plague is the only purpose left in his life, the only thing keeping him going. He may be aware that the fuel is running low, he has started to suspect that no one can still hear his bulletins, but he carries on. Maybe he'll be the heroic scientist who reports the vital discovery before he dies, so that others can make use of it, but... never mind, just keep going.

When he accidentally destroys the TS-19 samples, *it's over*. He has failed, his wife's sacrifice was for nothing, the facts he was avoiding before no longer matter, and he broadcasts his intention to end his own life.

When the group shows up, he indulges in the last pleasures that can be had: dinner with friends, some indulgences for his guests, and the joy of explaining science to the uninitiated. He tells them to conserve power, in order to make this idyll last a little longer (or maybe just out of habit). He doesn't tell them what's coming because that would spoil the time they have. He doesn't mount a scavenging mission because there's no point; without the TS-19 samples he has no hope of solving the riddle, and even if he could he now accepts the fact that it wouldn't make any difference. He's tired, he misses his wife, and he'd like to have a pleasant last meal and turn in.